How to see buffer interaction when Ert test is running like in Edebug
Ert test doesn't display interaction with working buffer like Edebug.
Simply, I started an Ert test that opens a buffer like:
(ert-deftest my-test ()
  (let* (...)
    (with-temp-buffer
      (erase-buffer)
      (insert-file-contents-literally file-name)
       TEST-BODY)))) 

I chose with-temp-buffer and insert-file-contents-literally to avoid side effects, how the Emacs reference manual specifies.
In TEST-BODY there is the programmer interaction with opened temporary buffer where he press keys that calls functions and depending on the error generated by these function in buffer the test is pass or not. OK. No matters what the programmer does in buffer.
When run test with M-x ert RET (default t) RET, ERT program doesn't display the buffer where the interaction happens, it puts only the minibuffer where programmer sees the outputs and type commands.
I make a comparison with Edebug where the behavior is different. If Edebug instrumented function contains a call to find-file: (find-file FILE), then corespondent buffer of FILE is opened below edebug buffer, where programmer sees what happens in buffer (where the cursor jumps, text highlights, etc).
How to make Ert test program to display the interacting buffer?
